# compatibilty view

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

since turning on compatibility view on a certain web site, the resolution on my web cam has beeb reduced, how do i turn of compatibility view to get my web cam working properly again. i,ve checked the resolution of the web cam and it,s the same as it,s allways been.
thanks.
tommy

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this Microsoft support article for configuring your [Compatibility View settings.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197)

If you've already enabled it, go to your Compatibility View settings and remove it from the list.

[image]